# How do you adjust overhang.title's position in SceneGraph in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I set overhang in my Roku App, but the position of the overhang title seems too high. I want to adjust it but I could not find an offset option like logoBaselineOffset or leftDividerVertOffset.
Does anybody meet a similar problem and how do you solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you have defined your layout in the xml. You can debug/define your layout using the RALE tool.
http://devtools.web.roku.com/#rale-tool